# Why are there so few ion-trap experiments studying quantum trajectories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements, open-quantum-systems

The quantum trajectory theory describes the behaviour of a quantum system under continuous monitoring. Initially it is theoretically studied in quantum optics and single atom scenario (e.g., ion trap setups). But as far as I know, experimental studies on quantum trajectories are mainly done in superconducting quantum circuits. So my question is *why there are so few experiments using ion traps? Is it because of experimental limitations?* Or if there are such ion trap experiments, could you help to list some of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first observations of quantum trajectories were famously carried out using trapped ions, based on a proposal for "electron shelving" by Dehmelt: see the [Plenio & Knight review](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9702007) for a historical discussion. The key experimental papers to check out are [Sauter et al., Phys. Rev. Lett. 57, 1696 (1986)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.57.1696) and [Bergquist et al., Phys. Rev. Lett. 57, 1699 (1986)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.57.1699) (the latter is free to read). As you can see, these results are several decades old. If more papers are published on quantum trajectories in superconducting circuits nowadays, it is probably just because the technology is much newer and still under development. But electron shelving is used routinely across many platforms --- trapped ions, NV centres, superconducting qubits etc. --- to efficiently measure electronic states of individual (real or artificial) atoms.

The above experiments demonstrate jump-like trajectories corresponding to direct detection of the emitted photons. One can also consider diffusive trajectories that arise from a homodyne-based detection scheme. Such a measurement scheme has been realised to implement feedback cooling of the motion of a trapped ion: see for example [Bushev et al., Phys. Rev. Lett. 96, 043003 (2006)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.96.043003) and references therein.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links and explanations! I would like to ask further questions: these ion trap experiments are studying "quantum jump" type of trajectories. Is there any ion trap experiments studing "quantum diffusion" type of trajectories, e.g., monitoring the emitted photons by homodyne detection? These type of experiemnts are done in e.g.,

Comment: [Murch et al., Nature 502, 211-214 (2013)](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature12539), [Minev et al., Nature 570, 200-204 (2019)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1287-z). I am wondering is there any smilar experiments in ion trap experiments?

Comment: Yes homodyne detection can also be realised in trapped ions: see my updated answer. My basic theorist understanding is that direct detection ($\to$quantum jumps) is easier to realise in trapped ions because efficient single-photon detectors are available at optical frequencies. Heterodyne schemes ($\to$quantum state diffusion) are more natural for superconducting qubits, since single-photon detectors are hard to build at microwave frequency but qubit-cavity couplings can be much stronger. The latter allow for implementing dispersive cavity-QED couplings for homodyne-based qubit readout.

Comment: For an experiment like the Minev one at least, I believe that one requires nearly perfect detection of the photons emitted from the qubit when it is 'bright'. This generally doesn't happen in ion traps; the ions are confined in free space and the fraction of photons collected when they fluoresce is determined by optical access. An ion trapped in an optical cavity or near a waveguide might be capable of an analogous experiment.

Comment: @Rococo I see. If one doesn't need to "catch and reverse", just want to see the diffusion trajectories in ion traps, then it is still possible even the detetcion is not perfect?

Comment: @Mark Mitchison Ok, I see. So it should be possible to realize quantum state diffusion in ion traps by homodyne-based qubit readout.